# Amazon ELBで通信の暗号化をする際、HTTPS(SSL/TLS)とTCPの使い分けがわかりません

Tags: tcp, https, amazon-elb

次の画像ではAmazon ELBを経由するネットワーク経路の暗号化を示したものです。
この画像の内容について質問です。

### 質問

１、２、３のパターンのうち３がよくわかりません。（TCPにするメリットがわかりません）
TCPではなくHTTPSで良いのでは？と思いました。

### 調べたこと

１はELBにSSL証明書を付与し、ELB〜サーバー(EC2)間は暗号化しないことでサーバーへの負荷を減らせる
２はELB,サーバー(EC2)それぞれにSSL証明書を付与し、クライアント〜サーバー(EC2)間を全て暗号化できる。よりセキュアになる
と理解しています。

３はクライアントの証明書を認証する場合使用するそうなのですがHTTPSではダメなのでしょうか？

また、SSLを調べたところ『TCPを拡張した形で利用するプロトコル』と出てきました。

### お願い

HTTP+SSL=HTTPSでありSSL≒TCPとなると

HTTPS→通信するデータ自体を暗号化する
SSL≒TCP→通信自体を暗号化する
と思いました。

ということはTCPを設定するメリットや理由は
TCPの方がその通信全体を暗号化できるからでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

１．２．はTLS Terminationと言ってELBがいったん暗号化を解除します。そのため、ELBは暗号化されていた通信の内容を読むことができ、内容に応じた負荷分散が可能になります。
３．は暗号化を解除しないため、通信内容に依存しない負荷分散しかできないことになります。

３．のメリットはこの点にあり、AWS側リソースであるELBと言えど、暗号化された内容を知られずに通信することができます。質問文にも挙げられているようにクライアント証明書なども同様です。
「ELBに暗号化された内容を知られずに通信することができる」にメリットを感じるかは個人差があり、質問者さんには価値を見出せなかっただけかと思います。

Comment: とてもわかりやすい回答ありがとうございます！